# Timing a UITouch instance

Tags: iphone, uigesturerecognizer, uitouch

I have a UIView with a gestureRecognizer for a tap or a slide, but I want to be able to time the users touch time and if it is larger than a certain time value I want to trigger another method.

How is the time of a UITouch gesture accessed?

Thanks

Comment: Not an answer to your actual question, but will a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

The timestamp property of UITouch is probably what you want.

```
 [touch timestamp]
```

Comment: Thanks. but how is this continuously checked? some way to do (pseudo) while touch detected, grab timestamp add differences from previous timestamp, if time > some value, do something. Is there are way to get the state of the touch or gesture recognizer. to see if it is still being touched, or what is a good way to do this?

Comment: Ok for that look at these methods: touchesBegan:withEvent:, touchesMoved:withEvent,touchesEnded:withEvent, touchesCancelled:withEvent:  Subclass UIGestureRecognizer to use them.  Record the time in the touchesBegan method and the end time in the touchesEnded method.